# Panorama is shrinking background picture which is from Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I have a simple page with a panorama and a button which have to change a background picture of panorama. Originally picture is 1200x800.
 If I use a picture from Resources, everything is fine:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("Resources/Panorama.png", UriKind.Relative);
var bitmap2 = new BitmapImage(uri);

// here from debugging: bitmap2.CreateOptions == DelayCreation, bitmap2.PixelWidth == 0 and bitmap2.PixelHeight == 0

var lcBrush2 = new ImageBrush() {
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    ImageSource = bitmap2 
};

panoMain.Background = lcBrush2;
```

but if I take a picture from Isolated Storage:

```
var picStream = ...getting a stream of file....;
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(picStream);

// here from debugging: bitmap.PixelWidth == 1200 and bitmap.PixelHeight == 800

var lcBrush = new ImageBrush() {
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    ImageSource = bitmap 
};

panoMain.Background = lcBrush;
```

then the picture is shrinked to 480x800

What I am doing wrong? Or it is a bug from MS?

Comment: Can you use the same brush loading code by loading the resource from a file? You will probably need to set the resource as CopyToOutput on its properties

Comment: Can you use bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri); in both pieces of code

Comment: I wanted to, but how to get an Isolated Storage with Uri?

Comment: When involving the UI for WP7 please also include the XAML code, this can say a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this is a bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/0743ee59-f407-4e8a-afc8-93569698a924/). One workaround from that thread:

> One work-around I have found is to set a "default" Background Image in
>   XAML which is of a desired size.  If I do this, then update the
>   Background property in my MainPage_Loaded event the new image shows as
>   the same size as the default image.

There is another workaround, with code, at the bottom of that thread.

Comment: @FactorMystic - In the AppHub upgrade,  it seems previous links have been killed. Here's the updated link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/0743ee59-f407-4e8a-afc8-93569698a924/